# Software to convert Video CD/DVD to single file with Xvid format

Tags: linux, video, ubuntu, media-converter

Video CDs or DVDs usually use formats that have large file size. In contrast, if the video is converted to Xvid format with same quality its size will be much lower on the disk.

I need a software that could convert a video CD or DVD to Xvid format.

I need it when I insert the video CD or DVD, read directly from the disk and convert it to the Xvid format and save it on my local drive.

The program must run on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This similar question might give you an answer. If not, I can type up a longer response later. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1704/iso-to-avi-converter-software

Comment: @ZeroFlux The software in the answer to the question you linked seems to help me. I should try it. But I think my question is not duplicate of that question. May be the answer is same. I decided to answer my question but I think it is better that you do it if you like. Otherwise I could.

Comment: @ZeroFlux I tested `handbrake`. It seems that it only can convert DVD videos, not CD videos. I am looking for a software that can convert both or another software for CD videos.

Comment: @PHPLearner it might also help if you could include the OS the software should be able to run on.

Comment: @Izzy The question is updated.

Comment: Ah, good. In that case a hint to our sister site: [How to rip DVD's in high quality](http://askubuntu.com/q/111678/68291) Maybe one of the solutions mentioned there can do that (not sure, though).

Answer (score 2):

I did what i need using **VLC media player**. To install ** VLC media player** you may use your package manager (such as Synaptic) or may use following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

After installing and running the program, in *Media* menu select *Convert / Save* item or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
[image: Media menu]
In *Open Media* window select *Disc* tab. Select source device in *Disc device* section and click on *Convert / Save*.
[image: Open Media window]
*Convert* window will be opened. Under *profile* select output file format and specify a *Destination file*. Then click *Start*.
[image: Convert window]