# VOB to AVI Encoder

Tags: video, media-converter, encoding

I have an old video of me skydiving in Newzealand. Which is funny and awesome at the same time. What's not awesome is the VOB format, which is an outdated video format for CD players.

I just saw that tmpeg which I used back in the days is gone commercial. I'm not the video cutting expert here. Do you have any recommendation for a good open-source conversion tool?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iso to avi converter software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1704/3579)

Comment: I'm not sure because this is not an ISO neither a DVD. It's really old like with old menus and stuff :D

Comment: actually it's the DVD ripped into ISO image, so inside the image there are VOB files

Comment: Seems like a VCD. Can you play the file now on some video player? If so, which one?

Comment: @phuclv it's not a DVD I got here I think user3169 is correct on that part. That looks like a stone age VCD ;)

Comment: VCD are MPEG1 files. You can open it directly just as DVD MPEG2 VOB files. Any converter can convert it but you'll lose some quality. If size is not a problem just copy the video files to hard disk